# C++ atomics Correct memory order and thread fencing for a shared_ptr implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading, smart-pointers, stdatomic, compare-and-swap

After learning `std::atomic` and `std::memory_order` I wanted to experiment with writing a thread safe `shared_ptr<T>` and `weak_ptr<T>` implementation using atomics based on [Microsoft Blog: Inside STL: Smart pointers](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230814-00/?p=108597). I'm not sure what memory order to use when implementing `weak_ptr<T>::lock()` for the `compare_exchange_weak` loop.

Control Block:

```cpp
class control_block {
  public:
    constexpr control_block() : strong(1), weak(1) {}

    void inc_strong() { strong.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); }
    void inc_weak() { weak.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); }
    int32_t dec_strong() { return strong.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release); }
    int32_t dec_weak() { return weak.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release); }
    int32_t use_count() { return strong.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); }

  public:
    std::atomic<int32_t> strong;
    std::atomic<int32_t> weak;
};
```

Shared Pointer

```cpp
template<class T>
class shared_ptr {
  public:
    using element_type = T;
    using weak_type = weak_ptr<T>;

    friend class weak_ptr<T>;
  public:
    constexpr shared_ptr() noexcept: object(nullptr), blk(nullptr) {}

    explicit shared_ptr(T *ptr) : object(ptr), blk(new control_block()) {}

    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr &other) noexcept {
        object = other.object;
        blk = other.blk;
        if (blk) {
            blk->inc_strong();
        }
    }

    shared_ptr(shared_ptr &&other) noexcept {
        object = other.object;
        blk = other.blk;
        other.object = nullptr;
        other.blk = nullptr;
    }

    shared_ptr<T> &operator=(const shared_ptr &other) noexcept {
        if (this == &other) return *this;
        release_strong_ref();
        object = other.object;
        blk = other.blk;
        if (blk) {
            blk->inc_strong();
        }
        return *this;
    };

    shared_ptr<T> &operator=(shared_ptr &&other) noexcept {
        if (this == &other) return *this;
        object = other.object;
        blk = other.blk;
        other.object = nullptr;
        other.blk = nullptr;
        return *this;
    };

    ~shared_ptr() {
        release_strong_ref();
    }
  public:
    explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return blk != nullptr; }

    [[nodiscard]] element_type *get() const noexcept { return object; }
    [[nodiscard]] int32_t use_count() const noexcept { return blk ? blk->use_count() : 0; }
    T &operator*() const noexcept { return *object; }
    T *operator->() const noexcept { return object; }

  private:
    void release_strong_ref() noexcept {
        if (!blk) return;
        if (blk->dec_strong() == 1) {
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
            delete object;
            if (blk->dec_weak() == 1) {
                std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
                delete blk;
            }
        }
    }

  private:
    T *object;
    control_block *blk;
};
```

and Weak Pointer:

```cpp
template<class T>
class weak_ptr {
  public:
    using element_type = T;

    friend class shared_ptr<T>;
  public:
    constexpr weak_ptr() noexcept: object(nullptr), blk(nullptr) {};

    weak_ptr(const weak_ptr &other) noexcept {
        release_weak_ref();
        object = other.object;
        blk = other.blk;
        if (blk) {
            blk->inc_weak();
        }
    }

    weak_ptr(weak_ptr &&other) noexcept {
        object = other.object;
        blk = other.blk;
        other.object = nullptr;
        other.blk = nullptr;
    }

    template<class Y>
    weak_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y> &other) noexcept {
        if (!other) {
            object = nullptr;
            blk = nullptr;
            return;
        }
        object = other.object;
        blk = other.blk;
        blk->inc_weak();
    }

    ~weak_ptr() {
        release_weak_ref();
    }

    template<class Y>
    weak_ptr<T> &operator=(const shared_ptr<Y> &other) noexcept {
        release_weak_ref();
        if (!other) {
            object = nullptr;
            blk = nullptr;
            return *this;
        }
        object = other.object;
        blk = other.blk;
        blk->inc_weak();
        return *this;
    };

    weak_ptr<T> &operator=(const weak_ptr &other) noexcept {
        if (this == &other) return *this;
        release_weak_ref();
        object = other.object;
        blk = other.blk;
        if (blk) {
            blk->inc_weak();
        }
        return *this;
    };

    weak_ptr<T> &operator=(weak_ptr &&other) noexcept {
        if (this == &other) return *this;
        object = other.object;
        blk = other.blk;
        other.object = nullptr;
        other.blk = nullptr;
        return *this;
    };

  public:
    explicit operator bool() const noexcept { return blk != nullptr; }

    shared_ptr<T> lock() noexcept {
        if (!blk) return shared_ptr<T>();
        int32_t old = blk->strong.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        while (old > 0) {
            if (blk->strong.compare_exchange_weak(old, old + 1, std::memory_order_acquire)) {
                shared_ptr<T> ptr;
                ptr.object = object;
                ptr.blk = blk;
                return ptr;
            }
            old = blk->strong.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        }
        return shared_ptr<T>();
    }

    [[nodiscard]]int32_t use_count() const noexcept { return blk ? blk->use_count() : 0; }
    [[nodiscard]]bool expired() const noexcept { return use_count() == 0; }

  private:
    void release_weak_ref() noexcept {
        if (!blk) return;
        if (blk->dec_weak() == 1) {
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
            delete blk;
        }
    }

  private:
    T *object;
    control_block *blk;
};
```

When doing the compare exchange loop to check if the strong reference is non zero, what should be the success and failure memory order? And, in the destructor for the `shared_ptr<T>` and `weak_ptr<T>`, is the memory order of the `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire)` correct to fence the deletion of the control block and the object?

I have tried using it as a drop in replacement in some multithreaded app on x86 and it seems to behave fine. But I'm worried due to the memory arch of other platforms, there are bugs within this code that is not showing up.

On a further note: How would one go about testing the threading safety beyond trying to reason about the memory order.

Comment: Doing `old = blk->strong.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);` in your `lock()` loop is wrong. `compare_exchange_weak` already loads the current value on failure, so you're not doing any good by loading it another time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is only a partial answer to the problem:*

You can use [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/290230034092898981488d0716ddae43bd36c09f/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/shared_ptr_base.h#L266) as reference (code reformatted):

> ```cpp
> template<>
> inline bool _Sp_counted_base<_S_atomic>::_M_add_ref_lock_nothrow() noexcept
> {
>     // Perform lock-free add-if-not-zero operation.
>     _Atomic_word __count = _M_get_use_count();
>     do
>     {
>         if (__count == 0)
>             return false;
>         // Replace the current counter value with the old value + 1, as
>         // long as it's not changed meanwhile.
>     }
>     while (!__atomic_compare_exchange_n(&_M_use_count, &__count, __count + 1, true,
>         __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL, __ATOMIC_RELAXED));
>     return true;
> }
> ```

Firstly, note that you have a pointless `load` operation in your loop:

> ```cpp
> old = blk->strong.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
> ```

When `std::compare_exchange` fails, the current value is loaded into `old` anyway, so this load does nothing for you.

Secondly:

- For failure, you can use `relaxed` order. The `compare_exchange` is a read-modify-write operation anyway and you don't do anything with the value between loading it and retrying the `compare_exchange`, so any stronger memory order is useless.
- For success, `relaxed` seems sufficient to me ([MSVC uses `relaxed` here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/a8888806c6960f1687590ffd4244794c753aa819/stl/inc/memory#L1128), although libstdc++ uses `acq_rel`). I'm not confident in saying whether `acq_rel` is absolutely necessary, but you cold use it to be on the safe side.